# Обособление вводной конструкции у В. Набокова

Tags: вставная-конструкция

Из стихотворения **[В. Набокова "Родина"](http://nabokov-lit.ru/nabokov/stihi/259.htm):**

```
 Над шумливой рекою, — тяжелой
 от лазури влекомых небес, —
 раскачнулся и замер веселый,
 но еще неуверенный лес.
```

Чем обоснована постановка **симметричных знаков**  (запятая и тире)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая и тире — средство с наибольшей раздвижкой слов в тексте. В этом четверостишье оно одно способно удержать вводную конструкцию, поделённой рифмой на этажи, от расслоения и разрушения. В целостности конструкции не должно было возникнуть сомнений.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.